# How to add condition on the basis of plugin version, theme development WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am working on theme development and want to add condition to get revolution slider alias. Now Revolution Slider 6.x changed function to get alias of slider. Now I want to add a condition on the basis of revolution slider plugin basis.

I have no idea about how we can apply condition on plugin version basis.

Requirement::
I want to add a condition like, if rev_slider plugin version is less than 6.0 than apply old code otherwise I want to apply newer code to get sliders.

This is revolution slider guideline to get alias:: https://www.themepunch.com/faq/developer-guide-get-all-slider-alias/

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Plugin data by calling get_plugin_data() function, by that you can get the version of the plugin and then you can put the condition, Please check this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_data/)